# Is there a way to cast type parameter?

Tags: c#

Can I use type parameter as implementing specific interface at Runtime without Reflection?
The following pseudocode is what I want to do.

```
void Run1<T> ()
{
    // ...
    if (typeof (IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom (typeof (T)) {
        Run2<T implementing IEnumerable> (); // <- use T as implementing IEnumerable
    }
    // ...
}

void Run2<T> () where T : IEnumerable
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I don't believe there's a simple way you can do that.

If you're in control of all the code, you could have a *public* version of `Run2` with the constraint, but a *private* implementation of `Run2` without the constraint, which you call from `Run1`:

```
public void Run1<T>()
{
    // ...
    if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))
    {
        Run2Impl<T>();
    }
    // ...
}

public void Run2<T>() where T : IEnumerable
{
    Run2Impl<T>();
}

private void Run2Impl<T>()
{
    // Need to cast any values of T to IEnumerable here
}
```

Comment: With a bit of reflection, it appears that it is not that difficult.

Comment: @Alex: Yes, it can be done with reflection - but the OP was specifically asking for a solution without using reflection.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to drop the requirement of not using reflection, you could do this using a little detour.

```
public class Tester
{
    private static readonly MethodInfo _run2Method = typeof(Tester).GetMethod("Run2");

    public void Run1<T>()
    {
        if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
            Run2AsIEnumerable<T>();
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Run1 for {0}", typeof(T));
    }

    public void Run2<T>() where T : IEnumerable
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Run2 for {0}", typeof(T));
    }

    private void Run2AsIEnumerable<T>()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Detour to run2 for {0}", typeof(T));
        var method = _run2Method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T));
        method.Invoke(this, new object[0]);
    }
}
```

Note that this could be made a bit more efficient by building and caching delegates for specific types on-demand.

The output of this:

```
new Tester().Run1<IEnumerable<int>>();
```

is:

```
Detour to run2 for System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32]
Run2 for System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32]
```